# JS Loop through AJAX-response array filled with arrays, how to get the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, loops

I'm doing an ajax-call, which returns an array. This returned array consists of arrays, in each of which is another array :

[image: image for clarification - response in console]

I'm trying to do a for-loop in javascript, to create an element for each of these arrays in the response-array. My code:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: $("base").attr('href') + 'json/handler',
        data : data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            for(var entry in data) {

            $('#testdiv').prepend("<span class='test' data-unixtime='" + entry[2] + "'>" + entry[0] + "</span><br>");

            }
```

`entry[0]` and `entry[2]` just return a single (random) number. I also cant seem to reach the data in the nested-array by using `entry[1][tablename]`.

I tried multiple ways of doing the loop and got a few different (random?) numbers out of it, but nothing has come even close to the values I need.

Comment: Try logging what `entry` is, it's not what you think it is. Also don't use `for in` on arrays.

Comment: I'm used to Twig (PHP), so I made this mistake! This way seems to work: `var arrayLength = data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    alert(data[i]);`   thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to add dataType as attribute of ajax function?

dataType:'json'

the remember to add "" between the key that you want to access `"tablename"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop, but you'd be better with foreach which is cleaner to use. As for the nested object (note: object, not array) you'd access that by calling it's property, not trying to access an index. Here's a js bin that should help you along! ;) You should just be able to drop the data.forEach section into your ajax response function (success: function(data){})

https://jsbin.com/dorayeriku/1/edit?html,js,output

```
   var data = [
  ['10:00', {tablename: 'table1', tableseats: 2}, '1234567'],
  ['11:00', {tablename: 'table2', tableseats: 2}, '1234568'],
  ['12:00', {tablename: 'table3', tableseats: 2}, '1234569'],
          ]


    data.forEach((entry) => {
      $('#testdiv').prepend("<span class='test' data-unixtime='" + entry[2] + "'>time: " + entry[0] + "<br/> tablename: " + entry[1].tablename +"<br/>table seats:" + entry[1].tableseats + "<br/><br/></span><br>");
    })
```

Any questions or other help you need, just fire them at me :)

Comment: For record, here's all three ways, including yours that wasn't working, you should be able to work out why, but if you want more detail I'm happy to oblige. https://jsbin.com/nimuluqoho/edit?js,output